How to separate front-end and back-end properly in github?
I'm having one problem with a project I will start working with a team, this is my very first time I am working with other people so I'm unsure how to do it properly.
The problem is that we have two folders in our project, one for backend and other for frontend that I will be working on, but for example, when I push my work to github, it will change the commits that were made in the backend to the same ones that I made on frontend. I use git pull to update entire project that changes were made, but when I push, instead of only adding commits to the frontend, the same commits are forwarded to backend even though I didn't touch in any of it.
I haven't found a solution for this yet, if someone could please help me.


When you say "project" do you mean "repository"? Both folders are in the same repository? 2) What do you mean by "change the commits" or "forwarded to backend"? Commits do not change. Do you mean your commits which only change the backend also show up when you look at the frontend? Some screenshots would clarify. 3) If that's all true, this is normal. Commits apply to the entire repository. It doesn't matter which files are changed.


don't think this is a ci/cd related question and it has nothing to do with github-actions either.
for answering your question, github should display latest changes made to the current folder. so not sure how it not work for you, maybe post some screenshots here
